# Duplication of variables after inlining

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml, inline

I'm doing some self-study on inlining and alpha conversion, and there's a part which I cannot understand on the notes.

> However, since inlined expressions are copies of function bodies,
>   their variables may be duplicated and therefore must be α-converted
>   again.

Could anyone give me an example when the variables are duplicated after inline expansion, please? Thank you very much.

Comment: The citation is from a paper of min-caml, right?

Comment: @nekketsuuu Yes. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the following program.

```
let f x =
  let a = 42 in
  x + a

let () =
  let p = f 1 in
  let q = f 2 in
  print_int (p + q)
```

If you make `f` inlined, then the above program is converted as below.

```
let () =
  let p =
    let a = 42 in
    1 + a
  in
  let q =
    let a = 42 in
    2 + a
  in
  print_int (p + q)
```

Then there are two variables named `a`. So alpha-conversion is needed if you want to each variable has an individual name.